# Azure VM latency

Tags: azure

I have a VM setup on Azure in "South Brazil" location hosting a WCF service. Although I'm also in Brazil, latency to reach my service in the VM is ~200ms. I have the same service deployed in two other Brazilian hosts and latency to both of them is <60ms.

I've also seen people doing some tests on other Azure datacenters, and latency seems to always be ~50ms as well when near them.

I initially thought that it could be a VM size-related problem, but changing the size to D3 (which is *kinda* overkill to my service: CPU stays at only ~5%) didn't help at all, latency stayed the same.

Is this normal for South Brazil datacenters, or can it be something else?

Note that as I can't `ping` an Azure VM, I'm measuring the time in C# to `TcpClient.Connect` on port 80 with a StopWatch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you measure latency to the "other brazilian hosts" (<60ms) using `TcpClient.Connect` as well?

Comment: yes, I've tried both ping and `TcpClient.Connect` on those others.

Comment: Okay, have a look at @EEAA's answer. You could also try http://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net and see what you get

Comment: @Jukka Yes, I've seen that website before. Strangely enough, it reports ~200ms for North Central US and >400ms for Brazil South. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guaranteed latency on the public internet. Nor is there a way for any of us to gauge if the latency you're seeing is a result of network congestion or some other issue.

You'll need to take this up with Azure and your ISP.

Comment: Yes I know. But I only wanted to know if this is consistent with other people hosting VM's on Brazil South's datacenters. If it's not, then I would start trying to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I've seen from 5ms to 200ms. Not really an exact science. It's all about the route.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer. Do you have any suggestion of anything I can try, or anywhere I should look for, before contacting Azure support?

Comment: Test latency to your server from as many different ISPs as you can get access to.